# How to count all sent requests in jmeter 5.4.1?

Tags: performance, jmeter, throughput

I have a problem with one of the performance tests. I am using jmeter 5.4.1 with docker. Everything is behind f5, proxy, firewall etc but that is not the problem. My "headache" is that after about 30 minutes my throughput drops to almost zero. I'm looking for a solution to this situation and my question is : Does jmeter have the ability to count/summarize all requests sent, even if it doesn't get a response? The destination server gets everything that jmeter has sent, but I'm not sure if jmeter doesn't save requests only when it gets responses to them. example of my tests:
[image]

Update:
Active thread over time :

[image]

Transactions per second:
[image]

I don't have any timeouts set in my script and the response time is ok. No extended response times and yet the number of transactions is so mediocre....

Answer (score 1):

JMeter writes all executed [Sample Results](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) into its [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) so you if you have only [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers in your test plan - the number of rows in the .jtl file will be the number of requests sent by JMeter (minus one header row)

You can also track the requests which were sent by JMeter by loading the aforementioned .jtl results file into a listener like [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) or [Server Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) (the latter guy will display calls to [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) as well)

Comment: .... I was hoping I was wrong... then maybe you have some idea why jmeter suddenly decreases the number of requests sent? Could it be caused by a load balancer standing in front of the target server or porxy ? The interesting thing is that this request reduction is only affecting some of my samplers. The rest is going quite well.

Comment: First of all check the number of [active threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/), if is ok - check that JMeter is not overloaded, if JMeter is not overloaded check whether your system under test is not overloaded as JMeter waits for the previous response before sending the next request. The timeouts can be configured at "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) and the resource consumption can be checked using [PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)

Comment: I'll do that, thanks very much.

Comment: ech... Active threads over time looks fine but transaction over seconds - here I saw decreasing.....

Comment: Update main question - any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the cause. I exhausted all the threads on the JVM and that's why everything started to throttle... thank you for your help.

Comment: May I know how you fix the issue I think this is also the same issue I'm encountering. My request starts to drop after an hour. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I work with Kubernetes, dockers and so on. Long story short, I extended Xms and Xmx. Additionally I throw up some more memory(ram) and a little bit CPU. When I spice up my pods, everything was fine. Sry for my English.